# Can a system in its ground state tunnel to a state of higher energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have heard that quantum systems with higher energy than their ground states can tunnel and fall into a lower energy state. Can the reverse happen, quantum systems tunneling to a higher energy state?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be a bit cautious with statements like:

> tunnel and fall into a lower energy state

because energy is always conserved, so in any change the total energy of the final state is the same as the total energy of the initial state.

Suppose we take as an example a radioactive nucleus that decays by alpha decay, which is one of the classic examples where a system has to tunnel through a potential barrier in order to decay. If we just consider the nucleus than its energy is lowered by the decay so it is tempting to say that it tunnels through the barrier to a lower energy state. But the energy doesn't just disappear of course - it goes into the energy of the emitted alpha particle. So when you take the system as a whole it doesn't tunnel into a lower energy state, it tunnels into a state with the same energy.

The equations that describe the decay are time symmetric, so the reverse process is described by the same equations as the decay process. That means it's perfectly possible for an alpha particle colliding with the decayed nucleus to tunnel back into the undecayed state.

So in this sense yes a system can tunnel into a higher energy state, but as before this statement makes sense only if you are considering just the nucleus and ignoring the energy of the incoming alpha particle. Regardless of which way the system is tunnelling through the barrier the total energy remains the same.

In practice we only ever see the decay and we don't see alpha particles tunnelling back into the nucleus to *undecay* it. But this is simply because once the nucleus has decayed the probability of an alpha particle hitting it in just the right way to *undecay* it is exceedingly small. It's not the that reverse process is impossible, just that it's very unlikely.

Comment: * it tunnels into a state with the same energy but a greater probability.* I would leave away the part *but with a greater probability* as it is not correct. The dynamics in quantum mechanics is deterministic (Schrödinger equation) so there is no probabilities as long as you don't perform any measurements. You could reformulate this in term of transition amplitudes.

Comment: @domj33: hmm, yes, you're correct of course but I doubt that would make much sense to the OP.

Comment: Do you think it would make no sense because you assume the OP is undergraduate or so? I would insist just on the opposite philosophy: One should try to avoid wrong notions in simplified explanations to lay persons as these notions tend to stick and are likely to cause serious problems in understanding when approaching a more advanced understanding of QM. In any case I suggest to remove that part as you contradict it even yourself with what you write in the following (you give an example of a process with lower probability.)

Comment: This half-sentence *but with a greater probability* could lead to an understanding that tunnelling only happens into the direction of greater probability. You see what I mean?

Comment: Hmm, yes, OK you present a persuasive argument. Let me have a think and see if I can rewrite this to make it more accurate but still clear.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [tunneling diagram,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html) it says it all.

[image: barriere]

> As a particle approaches the barrier, it is described by a free particle wavefunction. When it reaches the barrier, it must satisfy the Schrodinger equation

[image: schrod]

> I have heard that quantum systems with higher energy than their ground states can tunnel and fall into a lower energy state.

After the barrier, whether there is a lower energy state it can decay to or not depends on the particular situation. It is a matter of conservation of energy that the particle cannot go to a higher energy state.

Comment: But it is also a matter of energy conservation that the particle can't go to a lower energy state, see the [answer of John Rennie](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/330391/27136)

Comment: Also, in the diagram it should say *reduced probability* **amplitude**

Comment: @domj33  we do not disagree with John, he is using the time inverse of the process shown above, reversing incident and exit wavefunction meaning

Comment: Well, in your answer one might understand that the energy of the system after the tunnelling can be lower but not higher because of energy conservation. But as long as you take only Hamiltonian dynamics into account, the energy of the total system is conserved whatsoever (except some short time violation because of fluctuations, which is reflected in the energy-time uncertainty relation). The decay to a lower state needs a reservoir where the energy can dissipate to.

Comment: @domj33 the figure shows that the energy is the same before and after the barrier. I just was hinting at a scenario where the particle comingout with the exit function finds an energy level to match that is a decay energy level not a stable state. I'd have to find an example but it is a possibility for the case of a free electron approaching a barrier and going through to be caught by an exact energy level outside the barrier as a resonance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if we consider Schrödinger equation and our initial state is an eigenstate (it doesn't matter ground or excited) then the system stays in this state during time evolution. "Fall into a lower energy state" happens under interaction with outer fields and that is why you can't describe your system by Schrödinger equation anymore.

So, to summarise: for closed system - no (Schrödinger equation leaves your initial eigenstate) and for open systems - yes, it is possible (for example, when atom absorbs photons with appropriate frequency). But "tunneling" is not an appropriate word, I would say transition between states.